# $wpd->insert is creating duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress function which runs every minute on a cron job. The $wpdb->insert code is as simple as this:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->bitcoin_price = $wpdb->prefix . 'bitcoin';

$gbpJson = @json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=GBP'));
$gbpArray = $gbpJson->Data[0];
$supplyJson = @json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshotfullbyid/?id=1182'));
$supplyArray = $supplyJson->Data->General;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $gbpArray->LastUpdateTS);

// This is inserting duplicates
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->bitcoin_price, array(
    "date" => $date,
    "gbp" => $gbpArray->Price,
    "supply" => $supplyArray->TotalCoinsMined
));
```

Yet when this runs every minute, I can find anything from 1 to 8 duplicate rows with exactly the same timestamp and data.

Comment: What is populating $gbpArray

Comment: Added the line in!

Comment: LastUpdateTS is provided by the remote server and is not constantly updated I have seen it stay the same between requests even spaced over a minute apart.

Comment: Ah nice, thanks - that must be the issue I'm seeing.